# Get more time sms verification from firebase authentication

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, sms-verification

Firebase phone number verification allows one time verification and sent a verification code to a phone number one time. But I need to get more verification code received in one phone number. I need to verify user several time. Is there any way to get more verification code in one number?

Comment: Is this for testing during development? If so, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#test-with-whitelisted-phone-numbers for how to whitelist a phone number for testing.

Comment: No. Its not only for developing time testing. I wanna verify my app user several time.

Answer (score 0):

You should try your apk to build in 'release' mode not in apk mode as per [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#test-with-whitelisted-phone-numbers)
For this go to the left bottom corner of your android studio select 'Build varient' and change it to release mode and let gradle sync.Try again with your problem might it get solved.

Comment: Using release mode, still I won't get a verification sms. Because 1 got a sms previously. How can I get more verification code in one number?